# Expiry Notification of from ios

Tags: ios, in-app-subscription

If I turn off auto renew before expiry of a in-app subscription, ios says it will send me DID_CHANGE_RENEWAL_STATUS, so after that when the actual expire time comes will ios again notify me?
As I am unable to turnoff auto renew on sandbox I am not sure what will actually happen

Comment: Is it purchased or trail version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer - no. Apple will not notify you when actual expires date comes. However, you can extract `expires_date` from other notifications and from receipt itself and remember it.